# What system functions does Antlr4 use?

Tags: c++, parsing, antlr, antlr4

I understand that antlr4 uses mutex.
I am building a system where all operation system services will be received as an input.
Mutex, threads, files and so on.
My questions are?

What other system function does antlr4 uses?

Is there a way to deliver a wrap around to antlr4 so the 'new mutex' will be used instead?
Or a way to disable those usages?

This is specifically for c++ sources.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I assume you are aware that the C++ runtime of ANTLR4 is open source: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/tree/master/runtime/Cpp

Comment: I am, and i was hoping to find a solution that doesn't involve modifying the code. Maybe also to know which calls exist